# How to show only specific rows in QSqlTableModel using combo box text?

Tags: qt, qcombobox, qsqltablemodel

I'm using `QSqlTableModel` in Qt C++ and I would like to show only the rows that contain the text that is in the `QComboBox`. For example, when I click on the "John" item in the combo box, the table view should show me only the names that start with "John". I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

The class for your needs is [QSortFilterProxyModel](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#details):

Rather than displaying your QSqlTableModel directly, put a QSortFilterProxyModel between the model and your view:

```
QSortFilterProxyModel* proxyModel = new QSortFilterProxyModel( this );

proxyModel->setSourceModel( yourQSqlTableModel );

yourView->setModel( proxyModel );
```

You can then sort or filter that model (check the `Sorting` and `Filtering` sections in the link at the top).

Comment: Thank you a lot Tim.Now i will look for the sorting and filtering

Answer (score 1):

By the way, if your type of filtering can be easily provided via SQL, you can just use QSqlTableModel's `setFilter()` method.